# Is it necessary to release this object in dealloc?

Tags: iphone, release, autorelease, dealloc

I have a question. In my .h:

```
NSString *string;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *string;
```

In my .m:

```
string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue];
```

Ok, "stringWithFormat" is an autorelease method. Need I release "string" in dealloc??

Answer (score 1):

only self.string = .... will retain your stringWithFormat.

so you dont need to release it. but beware that you string will be released and your app get crashed when your try later to access it. if you want to keep your string so make

```
self.string = .....
```

and release it on dealloc

Answer (score 0):

If the string that you are declaring is a part of the property in the above code then yes, even though you have to initialize it. The ownership is still yours to take care off.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are applied to property only.
Properties can not be accessed directly. It can be accessed via "." only.

So, when you write,

```
string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue];
```

you are accessing variable. So, no retain will be called on it. Also, `stringWithFormat` will return autoreleased object. So, no need to release it in dealloc. However, you can not access this variable beyond the scope because you do not know, when will it get released.

If you write,

```
self.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue];
```

you are accessing property and its value will be retained. So, you will have to release it in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

## Just Use ARC.

Seriously. It means you no longer need to worry about retain/release (though you do have to worry about reference cycles, which you would have had to worry about anyway).

If you are not using ARC, then the code above crashes becaus you are not taking "ownership" of the string (by retaining it). Either retain it correctly:

```
[string release];
string=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue] retain];
```

Or use the setter, which (if it is automatically generated) will retain it correctly:

```
self.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue];
```

In `-dealloc`, you then have to release the ivar, or you can just use the setter (which will release it automatically for you):

```
self.string = nil;
```

Before ARC, my rule of thumb was to *almost always* use the property syntax, since it just does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
 string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue];
```

do this:

```
 self.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", otherStringWithValue];
```

Now, you need to release the string in your dealloc. Though, the +stringWithFormat returns autorelased object but you've declared a retained property so, you're responsible for releasing it.

Answer (score -2):

This code will introduce memory leak because stringWithFormat returns autorelease object and you have retain string, so when you assign string the value of  stringWithFormat it will provide new autorelease object.But whatever memory you have retained for string is still there because its retain count is still 1, so it will not get released.but if you tried to release string it will crash because after assignment it will contain autorelease object.

Comment: Every sentence of this is completely wrong. 1) There will not be a memory leak -- there will be the opposite, a dangling pointer 2) that the property is declared as retain is irrelevant because he's not using the property at all 3) the string is autoreleased which means it will get released and deallocated (since nobody retains it) some time after the method, and when you try to send any message to the object at that variable, you will get undefined behavior because the pointer no longer points to a valid object

Comment: Ok I agree with your comment that there will be dangling pointer.But now my question is property declared as retail is irrelevant because he's not using the property at all, why?If this is the case then after assigning string value if I perform [self.string release] in dealloc, then according to you it should not get crashed since both are different.

Comment: It's not using the property. It's using the instance variable directly. What do you think property means? It's just a getter and setter. If you synthesize the property, the getter and setter serve to access the instance variable. i.e. `self.string` means `string` and `self.string = foo` means `[string release]; string = [foo retain];` since you set it as retain. In both cases you are using the instance variable `string`, but in one case it's retaining and the other not.